# What does the initialKey parameter do in the Pager constructor

Tags: android, pager, android-paging, android-paging-3

I am trying to understand what the `initialKey` does in the `Pager` constructor, but I cannot find any sort of explanation, not even in the official documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/Pager#%3Cinit%3E(androidx.paging.PagingConfig,%20androidx.paging.Pager.Key,%20androidx.paging.RemoteMediator,%20kotlin.Function0)

[image]

---

Can anyone explain what it does or how it works and how to use it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource.LoadResult.Page#nextKey:androidx.paging.PagingSource.LoadResult.Page.Key
Seems to be the page you want to start the pagination from. `null` by default

Comment: @Eselfar Thanks, but it is not clear what it refers to nor how it can be used. Is it the number of a page to load directly, the number of the items' position in the paged list, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing I believe the `initialKey` param is meant to indicate a position in the list, not a page.

I did two tests with varying page sizes.

Table with 2000 entries

Page sizes

- 10
- 20
- 100
- 123

For each page size I used the following as the `initialKey` for an item at position X

- `initialKey` = X

  - this uses the item position as the `initialKey`
- `initialKey` = X / page size

  - this uses the page in which the item is part of

For all results the item would always be correctly loaded in the initial/first chunk of data when I used the `initialKey` = X. It always failed when I used it as page size.

I am not sure if this is conclusive, but this was my conclusion from the limited tests for my problem.